# How do I create a new file under source control in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We just moved our database into TFS, and I was wondering if there is a way to create a new file automatically under source control in whatever file I am in now?

I've been looking, and everything is about adding an existing file.  Which is what I've been doing - creating a new file in VS, saving it to whatever folder it will be in, then adding - all of which can take 5-20 clicks depending on which folder I last saved a file in.  I'm looking for a way to add a new file automatically to whatever folder I am in in Source Control Explorer, the same why I can add a new folder.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is your solution and project binding to source control setup correctly? If it is, adding a new file to the project will automatically add it to TFS and the only thing you will need to do is check it in.

Comment: It's not in a solution at all - just files under source control.  And that still wouldn't solve the must create than solve in the correct place issue that seems to be holding me up the most.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Visual Studio then I would recommend installing the TFS 201x Power Tools. This will give you explorer access.

Just create a file and right click on it in Windows Explorer and add it...

Comment: I actually am using VS, just as a worse version of SSMS.  However I will try this since it may make it easier just to work in SSMS.  I'll still need to keep switching between both programs but it will be better than the frustration with the saves.  Thank you.